# comboBox(WPF) displays selected item only for the first selection, changes only text after the first selection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, wpf-controls

I had to make the following combobox for a wpf application,[image]

for the following type

```
public class Protocol
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string Name {get;set}
    public int Speed {get;set}
    public int Security {get;set}
}
```

So I made a custom Rating control which takes images and an Integer (i.e speed or security) to fill a rectangular WrapPanel with images.
    I created the DataTemplate for the combobox as follows

```
<ComboBox x:Name="pro" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Row="1" Margin="40,41,50,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Style="{StaticResource ProtocolComboBoxStyle}"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Protocols}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Protocol, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  Height="29" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Protocol}">
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="145" Padding="10,2,0,2" x:Name="text" Style="{StaticResource SettingsInactiveTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <controls:RatingControl FilledImage="pack://application:,,,/SampleApp;component/Resources/Images/Settings/SettingsHome/security_filled.png"
                                                        UnfilledImage="pack://application:,,,/SampleApp;component/Resources/Images/Settings/SettingsHome/security_unfilled.png"
                                                        Rating="{Binding Security}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <controls:RatingControl Margin="5,2,0,0" FilledImage="pack://application:,,,/SampleApp;component/Resources/Images/Settings/SettingsHome/speed_filled.png"
                                                        UnfilledImage="pack://application:,,,/SampleApp;component/Resources/Images/Settings/SettingsHome/speed_unfilled.png"
                                                        Rating="{Binding Speed}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

It works fine except after the initial selection, only the name of the protocol is changing in the togglebutton, the rating controls on the left do not change.

Also to mention, Selecting an item does change the binded selectedProtocol property in the viewmodel.

Please tell me if I am missing anything?
Thanks in advance

Comment: doesn't seem like your class is notifying of changes (INPC)

Comment: It does in the real project, I just coded here for reference

Comment: I dont think notifying of the properties has anything to do with the problem, these properties do not change they are just used to load the rating control once